# if $f'' >0$ prove that : $f(x+2)-f(x) \le f(x+5)-f(x+3)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f: R \to R$, differentiable twice such that $f'' > 0$

Prove that for every $ x>0$ exists:

$f(x+2)-f(x) \le f(x+5)-f(x+3)$

Any hints/suggestions? I got this problem at class and I couldn't figure out where to start.

Comment: A hint would be to use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: A further hint is that $f'$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x+2) - f(x) > f(x+5) - f(x+3)$. By the mean value theorem there is $x_1 \in (x, x+2)$ such that $f'(x_1) = \frac{f(x+2) - f(x)}{2}$ and $x_2 \in (x+3, x+5)$ such that $f'(x_2) = \frac{f(x+5) - f(x+3)}{2}$. So $f'(x_1) > f'(x_2)$, which is a contradiction since $f'' > 0$ ($f'$ should be increasing).

Comment: Indeed, the fact that $f'(x_1) > f'(x_2)$ implies there exists a point $y$ with $f''(y)<0$ is itself an application of the mean value theorem!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\dsc{\bracks{\fermi\pars{x + 2} - \fermi\pars{x}}
-\bracks{\fermi\pars{x + 5} - \fermi\pars{x + 3}}}
=\int_{x}^{x + 2}\fermi'\pars{t}\,\dd t
-\int_{x + 3}^{x + 5}\fermi'\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\int_{x}^{x + 2}\bracks{\fermi'\pars{t} - \fermi'\pars{t + 3}}
=-\int_{x}^{x + 2}\int_{t}^{t + 3}\fermi''\pars{s}\,\dd s\,\,\, \dsc{< 0}
\\[1cm]&\imp\quad\color{#66f}{\large%
\fermi\pars{x + 2} - \fermi\pars{x}
<\fermi\pars{x + 5} - \fermi\pars{x + 3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For a convex differentiable function $f$, the "incremental ratio"
$$\Delta_{x,y}=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}, \quad \Delta_{x,x}=f'(x) $$
is a non-decreasing function with respect to both its variables, so:
$$\Delta_{x+2,x}\leq\Delta_{x+2,x+2}\leq\Delta_{x+3,x+3}\leq\Delta_{x+5,x+3}.$$